# Iterator order breaks Table

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, scoping, iterators

Evaluating the following `Table` expression

```
Table[{s,p}, 
 {s,AstronomicalData[p,"Satellites"]}, 
 {p,AstronomicalData["Planet"]} 
];
```

produces the error message

> Table::iterb: Iterator {s, $Failed} does not have appropriate bounds.

But when I switch the iteration order, it works fine.

```
Table[{s,p}, 
 {p,AstronomicalData["Planet"]}, 
 {s,AstronomicalData[p,"Satellites"]} 
];
```

Why? (I don't think this is specific to AstronomicalData, that's just where I ran across it)

Comment: Later iterators may depend on earlier iterators, but not vice versa. Just like $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j =i}^n a_{ij}$ but not $\sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$.

Comment: Programmatically what is happening is that the symbols in the first iterator, other than `s`, are not localized and their values are taken from the global, system, or other contexts.  Hence the `AstronomicalData[p,"Satellites"]` fails probably because `p` does not have a value.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `EntityValue[PlanetData[], "Satellites", "EntityAssociation"]` instead of `Table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the larger context, this is something you have to get used to. I too believe it is not intuitive. The reason for that is as follows:

```
Table[{x, y}, {x, 3}, {y, 4}]
```

This simple iteration scheme (works also with `Sum`, `Integrate`, `Do`, etc) implies for me that `{x,3}` is closer to the body `{x,y}` and therefore it is the *inner* iteration. But in fact, it is the other way around. This is even more disturbing when looking at a `Do` loop

```
Do[
 Print[{x, y}],
 {x, 3},
 {y, 3}
]
```

It feels like the `x` iteration is the inner loop, but it isn't. That is the one thing you have to remember and then everything comes naturally. If you know this, then you also see that this table

```
Table[{x, y}, {x, 3}, {y, x}]
```

can be rewritten in two nested tables

```
Table[
 Table[{x, y}, 
   {y, x}],
 {x, 3}
]
```

Here it also becomes clear, why this doesn't feel right. Now the iterators are in the order you would expect and `{y,x}` comes first and `{x,3}` comes seconds.

Additionally, please note that in version 10+ `With` the order is really from outer to inner and since the definition lists are the first arguments this makes sense. Everyone instantly knows what is meant by

```
With[{x = 3}, {y = x + 1}, x + y]
```

Comment: It make sense to me, if I think of the order of evaluation (left to right, not outer to inner).  Somewhat confusing is that the first argument is held and, in a sense, evaluated last, that is, after each iterator variable has been given a value.  If the body came last, then nesting tables would keep iterators in the same order, like `With`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I mean, I obviously got used to it, but I see it differently. When I do `Table[body, {x,..}]` I want to iterate `x`. Now, if I *add* another iterator, then the natural way of thinking is: I already have an iteration, please iterate now this iteration. Instead, the new iteration becomes the inner iteration. However, Haskell's list comprehension does it the same way.